# Add custom filters in Datatable AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable, datatables

I have a `datatable` which shows data from web service call. Now as a filter which consists of multiple checkboxes , I want to filter the datatable records based on checkbox selected.

All values within these checkboxes persists in datatable inside a column.

Here is an image which shows, what I am looking -

[image]

( Kindly ignore the blue rectangle in the image )

The image has `Clinic` column whose values can be clinic1 , clinic2 etc.

So when I select any checkbox it should show that clinic records only.

Here is code to make datatable :-

```
$scope.options = {
  "bServerSide": false,
  "sAjaxSource": WEB_URL
  "sServerMethod": "POST",
  aaSorting: [
      [1, 'desc']
  ],
  aoColumns: [{
          mData: 'id'
      },
      {
          mData: 'payment_date'
      },
      {
          mData: 'transaction_id'
      },
      {
          mData: 'Appointment'
      }

  ],
  "aoColumnDefs": [{
          "aTargets": [0],
          "mData": 0,
          "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
              var ids = data;
              var date = full.date;
              if (typeof(data) !== "undefined") {
                  username1 = '<label class="i-checks m-b-none"><input type="checkbox" name="post[]"><i></i></label>';
              }


              return username1;
          }
      },
      {
          "aTargets": [1],
          "mData": 1,
          "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
              var paydate = '';
              if (typeof(data) !== "undefined") {
                  paydate = moment(data).format('LL h:mm:ss a');
              }
              return paydate;
          }
      },
      {
          "aTargets": [2],
          "mData": 2,
          "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
              var clinic_name = '';
              if (typeof(data) !== "undefined") {
                  clinic_name = data;
              }
              return clinic_name;
          }
      },

      {
          "aTargets": [3],
          "mData": 3,
          "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
              var uname = '';
              if (typeof(data) !== "undefined") {
                  uname = data.Patient.name;
              }
              return uname;
          }
      }

  ],

  };
```

And html file :-

```
<table table ui-jq="dataTable" ui-options="options" class="table table-striped b-t b-b table table-borderd"
id="userUploadTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
      </th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>clinic</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th>phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Code, code, code, please

Comment: Is the data paginated? or does it all get loaded on the web service call? If it's all loaded, then you can use basic array filters to manage it, assuming your datatable model is an array. If it's paginated, then each checkbox click will have to go back to the server with a parameter to get only the records for the chosen clinic.

Comment: @kennasoft : All data is coming at once from server, so how can I add custom filter to it.

Comment: As @Mistalis has said, we need to see some code in order to be able to help. Do share what you have done so far.

Comment: @kennasoft : Code added please check.

Comment: This is only the datatable, what about the bulk update drop-down with the checkboxes? How does it tie into your controller?